# django elasticsearch giving empty records while the database has records

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

models.py

```
class job(models.Model):
    job_title                   = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.job_title
```

documents.py

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Index
# from seeker.models import AppliedJobs
from employer.models import PostJob
# from access.models import SeekerRegister

jobs = Index('jobs')

@jobs.doc_type
class AppliedJobsDocument(DocType):
    class Meta:
        model = PostJob
        fields = [
            'job_title',

        ]
```

views.py

```
from .documents import AppliedJobsDocument
from django.http import JsonResponse

def search_applied_jobs(request):
    q = request.GET.get('q')
    print(q)
    jobs = AppliedJobsDocument.search().query("match", title=q)
    lst=[]
    dict ={}
    for i in jobs:
        print(i)
    return JsonResponse(lst,safe=False)
```

settings.py:

```
ELASTICSEARCH_DSL = {
    'default': {
        'hosts': 'localhost:9200'
    },
}

i have added 'django_elasticsearch_dsl' in the APP also
```

i am trying to use elastic search with django and above is my codes. 
i my database there is records but i am getting empty data when i am trying to print 
it in my console.

i have installed java and elastic search is coming in port localhost:9200 also

please have a look into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first index your data from database into elasticsearch. Then you will be able to execute queries on elasticsearch.

Comment: can i do it inside my docker-compose ??

Comment: I think you need to call some functions for doing this task. This can be done inside your docker-compose if you write some script and run the script inside docker-compose.